# WebView below AppBarLayout in CoordinatorLayout not working

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have made simple `WebView` with `NestedScrollView` which is working fine except when I open YouTube, the search bar of YouTube is not showing but when I start scrolling and `Toolbar` hiding I can see it.

my question is make `WebView` below the `Toolbar`? If I use RelativeLayout will it work?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivityt"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
   >
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.example.webviewcontexttest.NestedScrollWebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    
</FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a margin on top. Here is the full code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivityt"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
   >
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.example.webviewcontexttest.NestedScrollWebView
    android:id="@+id/web_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
    
</FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: i tried it it will work if i dont scoll it.if i scroll it toolbar hide and in place of toolbar white thing remain which makes webview not  fullscreen or scroll below the white thing

Comment: @mak That will remain so. I f you want good user experience, try removing the `ToolBar`  altogether

Comment: no remove toolbar,anyway thank you for ur help i will try to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

makes webview below toolbar

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_below="@id/appBarLayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.example.webviewcontexttest.NestedScrollWebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
     

        />

</FrameLayout>
```